# Configuration Locale changes unexpectedly

Tags: android

I have Activity 1, that when y click the back button at the topbar it opens another activity with an intent. I will put code with fake names because of enterprise politics.

When I click the back button (and inside OnCreate method also) the debug returns for resources.configuration.locales = [en_GB] and when the intent is executed, inside the onCreate method of Activity 2 i get this [es_ES,en_US,es_US]. I have all the activities that shows the language that is set as the language app in determined fragment, but in this activity I don't know why the languages are the device languages, not the app chosen one's.

Activity1 method that launches the second activity:

```
private fun showAndHandlerBackDialog() {
        val activityList = Intent(this, CancelCustomFieldsActivity::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(activityList, 20202)
    }
```

Activity2 onCreate

```
class CancelCustomFieldsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        resources.configuration.setLocale(Locale(LocaleManager.getLanguage()))
        val binding = ActivityCancelCustomFieldsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        binding.cfKeepBtn.onClick { finish() }
        binding.closeTv.onClick { finish() }
        binding.cfBackBtn.onClick {
            setResult(20202)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on this strange phenomena?

Tried to set the configuration with SetLocale method, and the first time it keeps appearing in spanish and the second time I open the activity in english. But don't understand how to do it to show it in the app's language at the first time